# Submit Button Chrome Extension Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm very new to chrome extensions but I'm trying to build one that will have users input a maximum value and the percentage they would like to take of it.  It will then return that percentage.  The purpose of this app is so weightlifters can easily take percentages of their lift while looking at their program.

Unfortunately I have been unable to figure out how to write values back to the webpage once a submit button is clicked. The code is below.  Any help would be appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <p>Please input maximum lift</p>
    <input type="number" id="max">Max</input><br><br>

    <input type="number" id="percent">%</input><br><br>

    <input type="submit" id="submit">

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
 var max = document.getElementById("max").value;

 var percent = document.getElementById("percent").value;

 function equate() {
  var math = Math.round(max *(percent/100));
  document.write = (math);
 }

 document.querySelector("submit").addEventListener('click', equate() {
  equate();
 });
```

I'm really not sure about how to use querySelector or addEventListener.

Manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Weightlifting Percentages",
"description": "A Chrome Extension to Calculate Weightlifting Percentages",
"version": "1.0",

"permissions": [
"tabs"
],

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text">Please input maximum lift</p>
<div id="input_1">

<input type="number" id="max"> Max</input><br><br>
  
</div
<div id="input_2">
  
<input type="number" id="percent"> %</input><br><br>
  
</div>

<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="popup()">

<script>
function popup(e) {
  var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  var percent = document.getElementById("percent").value;
  var math = (Math.round(max *(percent/100)));
  document.write(math);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelector() takes a CSS selector, like "#submit", not just "submit". And try

```
addEventListener('click', equate);
```